# Session get expire before the time set

Tags: asp.net, performance, session

I am getting log out from the `.NET` application before `session` get expired.We are using web farms with Inproc settings, We tried login using individual link for each server,still its kicking out of application within 5 -6 minutes.

Somtimes session will last till 1 hours.
 Its happening only for our applciation which deployed in this webserver,.
In mid of doing somthing, application is kicking uu out and says to login again.

We think of applying `state server/sql server`, but with inproc its working for all other application ,We try the link seperately for individual server ,then also its throwing session timou out.

PLease help whther any specific settings are there to resolve this,

Comment: If you're using WebFarm and Session , this is expected behavior.. You cannot predict which worker process will be handling the request

Answer (score 0):

You can read this [The ASP.NET Worker Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225480%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) ... And I would suggest to stay completely away from the Session object.... and implement own logic.... Although there are solutions where people have been able to implement custom SessionState to maintain data

Comment: But when we try with individaul link say server A and B,Seperate link to access the application,that time load balancing is not come in effect,But then also we getting timeout

Comment: Session has another effect of locking requests (if the session is writable).... Maybe you're experiencing that ...

Comment: Can u explain it little more

Comment: Would this help [Session State Uses a Reader-Writer Lock](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2006/05/21/session-state-uses-a-reader-writer-lock.aspx)

Comment: We are asked to checked our existing setting to sort this out ,we are fully stuck with the existing IIS settings and web .config

Comment: What i read from some of the posts ... don't keep the sessionstate settings in web.config and instead configure each page... use sessionstatemode write only where required else keep it none / read.... see if that gives some difference